# What is the training data input to the transformers (attention is all you need)?

Tags: deep-learning, transformer-model

Sorry I'm new to NLP. Please bear with me. Say I have two sentences:

French: Le chat mange.

English: The cat eats.

In the following text, I will denote a training data as a tuple `(x, y)`, where `x` is the input data and `y` is the annotation.

When I train a transformer network, do I A. input these two sentences synchronously as training data, i.e. `(Le chat mange, The cat eats)`? Or do I B. use
`((Le chat mange, ), The), ((Le chat mange, The), cat), ((Le chat mange, The cat), eats)` as training data?

If it's A, sounds like I have to wait for the network to produce the words one by one during training, which would not be parallelizable. So I guess it should be B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This "shifting" of the source sentence is done by applying the "mask" mentioned in the paper.

The mask looks like this

```
M=[0, 0, ..., 0
   1, 0, ..., 0
   1, 1, ..., 0]
```

In self attention, since the matrix `QK^T` (scaling factor ignored) represents the cross-correlation between the "queries" and the "keys", when the mask is applied: `M o (QK^T)` (`o` denotes elementwise multiplication), the correlations between the "current query" `Q[i,:]` and "future" keys `K[i+k,:]`, for `k=1,...,N-i` are ignored.